# How do I click on this button on my webbrowser? (visual basic)

Tags: vb.net

I’m looking for code to click on that button on webbrowser:

```
<a class="single_like_button btn3-wrap" onclick="openFbLWin_856604();">
<span>&nbsp;</span><div class="btn3">Subscribe</div></a>
```

I have tried that:

```
   For Each elem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
        If elem.GetAttribute("class") = "single_like_button btn3-wrap" Then
                elem.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
```

.

```
   For Each elem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
        If elem.GetAttribute("class") = "btn3" Then
                elem.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
```

.

```
For Each elem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
If elem.InnerText = "Subscribe" Then
elem.InvokeMember("click")
End If
```

.

```
For Each elem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
If elem.InnerText = "Subscribe" Then
elem.InvokeMember("click")
End If
```

And none works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Trim` method to remove the  whitespaces from both ends of the `InnerText` before check it:

```
For Each elem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
    If elem.InnerText.Trim = "Subscribe" Then
        elem.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next
```